# Adding string to bitmap image and saving it vb

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I try to get an Image object from a bitmap and then use it to create a graphics object.
Then I write something using the DrawString function and then save it. The image is saved successfully but its the string is not there. 
below is the code.

```
Dim gr As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(NewImage)
            gr.DrawString("testSting " & temp_click.Text, font, Brushes.Black, New PointF(10, 10))
            gr.Dispose()
            NewImage.Save("C:\step" & stepNo & ".jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue in C# with a PictureBox.  I ended up having to store a local copy of the bitmap's image, manipulated that local copy, then stored the image property of the picturebox equal to the local copy.  Here is my code:

```
  Bitmap bm = (Bitmap)pic.Image;

  Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bm);

  ...apply changes to image using g object...

  g.dispose();

  pic.Image = bm;

  pic.Save(....);
```

Hope this helps.